# Cosa significa "falcidiato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Ma non meno assurdo, se mi volto indietro, è accorgersi che mio fratello, cresciuto in un'epoca stretta fra due guerre e **falcidiata** dall'influenza spagnola, sia andato a cercarsi una morte lontana, nel cuore dell'Africa, grazie al difetto di fabbricazione di una cartuccia da caccia.

Non capisco bene il senso di "un'epoca falcidiata dall'influenza spagnola". Ho cercato il [significato di "falcidiare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/falcidiare/) e ho trovato

> Fare una falcidia, in senso fig

Ho cercato anche il significato di "falcidia", ma non sono sicura di aver capito. Significa che l'influenza produsse una forte reduzione della populazione?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La parola `falcidiare` è in relazione con la parola `falce` e all'azione di `falciare`. La `falcidia` è il sostantivo che ha un significato più che altro metaforico e drammatico. L'azione può essere paragonata al `mietere vittime`. L'immagine che vi corrisponde è l'angelo della morte che reca in mano una falce.

L'immagine allegata è tratta da Il Settimo Sigillo di Bergman (notare il capofila a destra).

[image]

Comment: Giusto, e in uno spirito più scherzoso ricordo anche [questo](https://vimeo.com/98694948).

Comment: Quindi l'influenza "mietette vittime" durante quell'epoca?

Comment: @Charo -     Sì moltissime: .... ***la Grande Influenza, o epidemia spagnola*** è una pandemia influenzale che fra il 1918 e il 1920 uccise decine di milioni di persone nel mondo. È stata descritta come la più grave forma di pandemia della storia dell'umanità, avendo ucciso più persone della terribile peste nera del XIV secolo; e della stessa Grande Guerra.

Comment: Grazie, @Josh61, capisco.

Comment: @Charo Comunque: la forma *mietette* al passato remoto non è molto usata, si preferisce *mieté* di norma, sebbene sia facilmente confondibile con il presente *miete*: *l'influenza mieté vittime*.

Comment: Grazie, @Bakuriu! Avevo il dubbio se usare "mieté" o "mietette".

Answer (score 4):

***[Falcidiare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/F/falcidiare.php):***

> - Fare una falcidia; decimare, ridurre considerevolmente:
>
>   - *l'epidemia falcidiò la popolazione; il suo patrimonio è stato falcidiato da quell'affare*

(Hoepli)

- Sì, falcidiare si usa spesso in riferimento ad eventi catastrofici che hanno avuto come conseguenze la perdita di cose o persone.

***[Falcidia](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=falcidia):***

> - Forte riduzione:
>
>   - *gli introiti hanno subito una pesante falcidia*
> - Strage (anche in senso figurato):
>
>   - *una falcidia di vite umane; gli esami sono stati una vera falcidia*

(Garzanti)

> - ***Etimologia:*** ← dal lat. (quărtam) falcidĭa(m) ‘quarto d’eredità’, dal nome del tribuno della plebe Publio Falcidio, che propose la legge (40 a.c.); ma con influsso di fălx fălcis ‘falce’.

Answer (score 1):

Credo che per "influenza" qui si intenda la malattia (vedi l'articolo su [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influenza_spagnola)). Quindi sì, la tua interpretazione è corretta.